# Why does Django auto_now_add fail with not null on insert or update

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to implement a data warehouse. So the django system will query an api at regular intervals to update the database. I am using client ids as the primary key which might be the problem but when I do save I obviously want it to create or update.

I get this error whatever I do!

django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "created" violates not-null constraint

So originally I just had my model like this:

```
class PersonalTaxClient(models.Model):

 created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
 updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
 invoice_client = models.ForeignKey(InvoiceClient, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
 client_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
 email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Then I tried:

```
class PersonalTaxClient(models.Model):

    created = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField()
    client_code = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key=True) 
    invoice_client = models.ForeignKey(InvoiceClient, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    client_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
#    history = HistoricalRecords()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ''' On save, update timestamps '''
        print(timezone.now())
        if not self.client_code:
            self.created = timezone.now()
        self.modified = timezone.now()
        return super(PersonalTaxClient, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

and try to update like this:

```
>>> from sbsite.models import PersonalTaxClient
>>> p = PersonalTaxClient(client_code="HHH001", client_name="Bob")
>>> p.save()
```

I get the same error. I've read about 20 other SO pages but am none the wiser..............!

Comment: Hello, did you already have the error with your original model using `auto_now_add=True` ? Also, in your example you're creating (and not updating an instance) of `PersonalTaxClient` and with your second model, that's normal it does not work.

Comment: `client_code` is your models primary key so when you provide it while creating it (or if an object already has it) Django thinks you are saving an _existing_ object to the database and gives you an error. There is a closed [ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17654) about this specific issue (although I might consider it a bug) perhaps you should try reopening it?

Comment: I would consider the best move to remove that `primary_key=True` from `client_code` and simply add a `unique=True` instead. And let Django use the default primary key it makes (you might have to delete the migrations and database, etc.)

Comment: Note: If you got that error when trying to _update_ an instance then that error is completely correct (if it was on creating this might be a bug). If you want to update an object you should first **get** it from the database `p = PersonalTaxClient.objects.get(client_code="HHH001")` then `p.client_name = "Bob"` and `p.save()`

Comment: Great stuff folks. Thanks a lot. I have to say I thought save() created or updated? How Django knows to UPDATE vs. INSERT¶
"You may have noticed Django database objects use the same save() method for creating and changing objects. Django abstracts the need to use INSERT or UPDATE SQL statements."

Comment: But I think I will try using the Django id as PK and change to unique=true. Thanks